# Javascript works inline but not externally

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm pretty new to JS and Jquery and wondering if someone could help please :)

I'm working with this following code to create a map, it work fine inline

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Map with GPX track</title>
<style type="text/css">
  html, body, #map_display { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function gpx() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_display"), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    });

    $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "/alan.gpx",
     dataType: "xml",
     success: function(xml) {
       var points = [];
       var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
       $(xml).find("trkpt").each(function() {
         var lat = $(this).attr("lat");
         var lon = $(this).attr("lon");
         var p = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
         points.push(p);
         bounds.extend(p);


       });

       var route = new google.maps.Polyline({

         path: points,
         strokeColor: "#FF00AA",
         strokeOpacity: .7,
         strokeWeight: 4
       });

       route.setMap(map);


       map.fitBounds(bounds);
     }
    });
  }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="gpx()">
  <div id="map_display"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm looking to put this into an external .js file but it just doesnt want to work

this is the JS file, the alert is there to tell me the script is being called

```
alert ("hello from script");

function gpx() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_display"), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });

    $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "alan.gpx",
     dataType: "xml",
     success: function(xml) {
       var points = [];
       var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
       $(xml).find("trkpt").each(function() {
         var lat = $(this).attr("lat");
         var lon = $(this).attr("lon");
         var p = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
         points.push(p);
         bounds.extend(p);
       });

       var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
         // use your own style here
         path: points,
         strokeColor: "#FF00AA",
         strokeOpacity: .7,
         strokeWeight: 4
       });

       poly.setMap(map);

       // fit bounds to track
       map.fitBounds(bounds);
     }
    });
  }
$(document).on("ready", gpx);
```

and the html file I'm using is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Import GPX file to Google Maps</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <div id="map_display"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ac-gpxscript.js"></script>
</html>
```

When I do this I get back an error 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null

I'm pretty sure I'm just missing something small in the js file but for the life of me I cannot figure out what anymore

I'm sure its that the JS is being called before the DOM is ready but I thought the $(document) command would only call it when the DOM was ready

Comment: Where is the element `map_canvas`? I think this should be `map_display`.

Comment: thats a side effect of me changing it to try and make it work, when they both match (as they should) I still get a blank page instead of a map

Comment: the script tags should be inside the body tag at its bottom.

Comment: ok thanks, i've tried that but there's still no map

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to those who contributed it this.

There is not an error either of the code blocks I supplied, there was an error in the CSS file which affected the styling and therefore didnt display the map correctly

Comment: Can you include the offending and fixed CSS in your answer?